# How to test if url accepting query parameters using pytest-djnago

Tags: pytest-django

My django webserver url accept query-parameters. For ex. "mydomain.com?emp_name=abc&dept=admin".

I want to automate this write a test using pytest-djnago to see if the url accepts the query parameters or not. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achive this.

My setup :
Django             3.2.12
django-test-curl   0.2.0
gunicorn           20.1.0
pytest             7.0.1
pytest-django      4.5.2

**1) By using pytest-curl-report plugin** (https://pypi.org/project/pytest-curl-report/)

I was getting below error after installing the "pytest-curl-report 0.5.4" plugin.

```
Error: 
`pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: Plugin 'curl-report' for hook
```

'pytest_runtest_makereport'
hookimpl definition: pytest_runtest_makereport(**multicall**, item, call)
Argument(s) {'**multicall**'} are declared in the hookimpl but can not be found in the hookspec`

I tired multiple install/unistall but it didnt helped.

Also I didnt found any fix this issue on google, so I skipped this one and decided to use django-test-curl plugin. See point no. 2)

**2) By using django-test-curl plugin** ("https://github.com/crccheck/django-test-curl")

```
$ pip3 install django-test-curl



Usage
from django_test_curl import CurlClient

    class SimpleTest(TestCase):
       def setUp(self):
            self.client = CurlClient()
    
        def test_details(self):
            response = self.client.curl("""
              curl http://localhost:8000/customer/details/
            """)
    
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    
            self.assertEqual(len(response.context['customers']), 5)
```